# How is the Lamp supposed to work in Reaktor?

Tags: synthesis, reaktor

How does the Lamp work? I just want to display that a signal has come into my module. I have tried using an Audio to Event module, but no luck.

There's a big red X on the Lamp input.

The Manual says that the Lamp responds to Hz (Frequency) input. That is what the Oscillator outputs, right?

[image: Attempt to use a Lamp to give feedback on Osc output]

Comment: The oscillator is polyphonic (yellow LED) and the lamp is monophonic (red LED), so that's why you can't patch them together like that. Options are: adding a voice combiner, taking only the signal from a certain voice, making the oscillator monophonic, using a lamp for each voice...

Comment: Wow. When you refer to "each voice" and "only a certain voice", would that refer to specific pitch inputs? I'm thinking not, because I understand that each "module" is basically a template that reaktor replicates for each simultaneous voice.

Comment: If an instrument is e.g. 6-voice polyphonic, you can use the FromVoice and ToVoice modules to work with signals from one of those six voices. Obvious example would be if you have a polyphonic (out-of-sync) LFO, and you want a lamp to show what speed it's set to, you'd take the LFO signal from voice 1.

Comment: You should probably delete or edit this question. The problem isn't really about how the lamp module works, but about how the red x indicates that you can't plug poly signals into mono inputs.

Comment: I am hoping to see a lot more Reaktor discourse in this forum so am more inclined to edit the question. How about this...

Comment: I think that an answer containing an example or two of how to use Lamps in Reaktor would be awesome and with your blessing, I can probably compose one. Or perhaps the question should be more along the lines of: how does Reaktor implement polyphony? I appreciate the suggestion to delete. If you still think that's the right direction, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on `@Your Uncle Bob`'s comments on the OP:

The Lamp reads a *Monophonic* audio signal in Hertz and updates it's LED-style display accordingly.

A Reaktor Instrument can be either Monophonic or Polyphonic:

[image: Number of Voices Input in Reaktor Instrument]

And many of the modules also can be set to Mono (or not):

[image: Mono checkbox checked]

As indicated in bottom right of the module:

[image: A mono module]

(Notice the RED Xs when a Poly signal is sent to a Mono input.)

[image: Module set to polyphonic]

When an Instrument is running in Polyphonic mode, each of the modules, instruments, etc, is actually a template that is duplicated for each of the polyphonic voices.

The Lamp is a mono-only module, so it will not accept polyphonic input. One option is to use a Voice Combiner module between the Poly module and the lamp:

[image: Lamp with a Voice Combiner]

Another option is to use a From Voice module, specifying which voice to send to the Lamp. In the following case, we use the lamp to display the frequency of an Oscillator being used as an LFO:

[image: Using a From Voice module]

This set-up doesn't work terribly well because the `Amplitude` knob on the LFO, if turned all the way down, removes ALL amplitude from the Volume Envelope.

Another module to be aware of is the Event Smoother:

[image: Event Smoother]

This will change the effect of the Square LFO above from sounding like Deep Deep Deep, with hard edges (and some clicking), to Weep Weep Weep, with soft edges.

I'm still pretty green as is obvious, but there's the basics for anyone else who's troubled with the Lamp.